# What is "add files via upload" commit message in GitHub repositories?

Tags: github, commit-message

I see lots of repositories in GitHub with this commit message: `Add files via upload`.

[image]

But I couldn't figure out how this (probably) automatic commit message is made. I looked around to find a clue, but I couldn't find any reference for setting this commit message as default or something.

Why and how some commits are done with this message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That seems to be the GitHub "**Upload files**" web GUI feature, as [described here](https://rudeboybert.github.io/SDS192/webpage.html):

> ### Publish your updated webpage onto GitHub Pages:
>
> From GitHub, click on “Upload files”

[image: https://rudeboybert.github.io/SDS192/static/images/rmarkdown_websites_3.png]

> Where it says “Drag additional files here to add them to your repository”, drag and drop all the files in your webpage.Rproj folder:
>
> - GitHub should now look like this.
>
>   - Commit and push your changes:
>   - At the bottom of the page where it says “Add files via upload”, write a commit message “Baby’s first commit”.
>   - Click on “Commit changes”.

[image: https://rudeboybert.github.io/SDS192/static/images/rmarkdown_websites_6.png]

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. I didn't even think if people upload their files into their repo using web GUI! Thanks.

Comment: @AliTou Yes, and apparently without changing the default commit message...